# Treat author of "inbook" entry as editor of "incollection" entry in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is a spin-off from [Move editor name in biblatex bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511090/move-editor-name-in-biblatex-bibliography), in which the editor string "edited by X" in a `biblatex` bibliography is replaced by "X edited" (and with the word "edited" translated in the local language".

The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511101/9077) extends this to cases where there's an article in a collection (`@incollection` entry), cf. the Weinreich 1968 entry in the MWE below.

What I would like as well, is this: When I'm citing a part of a book (with its own title and author, the `@inbook` entry), I'd like the authors of the book to follow the title of the book in a string "X wrote", parallel with the "X edited" case mentioned above.

For the Torp 1909 entry in the MWE below, then, I'd like it to look like this:

> Torp, Alf. 1909. Gamalnorsk ordavleiding. *Gamalnorsk ordbok. Med nynorsk tyding*. Marius Hægstad og Alf Torp skreiv. Kristiania: Det norske samlaget (Landsmaals-laget), s. xxviii-lxxi.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style = authoryear-comp,
    language = nynorsk,
    sortlocale = nn_NO]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % don't print "in" for any entry
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{title}{#1} % no quotes around titles in bibliography (print as is)

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}} % put editor in parenthesis when before publication year
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\usepackage{xpatch}
    \xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{\printtext[parens]}{\setunit*{\addperiod\space}\printtext}{}{} % remove parenthesis around year in bibliography

\DefineBibliographyStrings{nynorsk}{
    bibliography = {Tilvisingar},
    editor = {styr\adddot},
    editors = {styr\adddot},
    founder = {grunnar},
    founders = {grunnarar},
    references = {Tilvisingar},
    byauthor = {skreiv},
    byeditor = {styrde},
    byfounder = {grunnade},
    volume = {band},
    volumes = {band},
}

\renewbibmacro*{byauthor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    or
    test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {}
    {\printnames[byauthor]{author}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{author}{author}}}

\newbibmacro*{byeditorx:i}[1]{%
  \ifnameundef{#1}
    {}
    {\printnames[by#1]{#1}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{#1}{editor}%
     \newunit}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editor}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditorx}{%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editora}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editorb}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editorc}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \bibstring{bytranslator}}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{withothers}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@BOOK{flo1906,
    AUTHOR = "R. Flo",
    TITLE = "Midlandsmaal",
    YEAR = "1906",
    EDITOR = "Arne Garborg",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PUBLISHER = "Olaf Norlis forlag",
    SUBTITLE = "Etter framlegge fraa rettskrivingsnemndi i 1899"}

@BOOK{ordbogoverdetdanskesprog,
    TITLE = "Ordbog over det danske sprog",
    YEAR = "1919--56",
    EDITOR = "H. Juul-Jensen",
    EDITORA = "Verner Dahlerup",
    EDITORATYPE = "founder",
    LOCATION = "K{\o}benhavn",
    NOTE = "Udgivet af det danske sprog- og litteraturselskab",
    PUBLISHER = "Gyldendalske boghandel. Nordisk forlag",
    VOLUMES = "28"}

@INBOOK{torp1909,
    AUTHOR = "Alf Torp",
    BOOKTITLE = "Gamalnorsk ordbok",
    TITLE = "Gamalnorsk ordavleiding",
    YEAR = "1909",
    BOOKAUTHOR = "Marius H{\ae}gstad and Alf Torp",
    BOOKSUBTITLE = "Med nynorsk tyding",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PAGES = "xxviii--lxxi",
    PUBLISHER = "Det norske samlaget (Landsmaals-laget)"}

@INCOLLECTION{weinreich1968,
    AUTHOR = "Uriel Weinreich and William Labov and Marvin I. Herzog",
    BOOKTITLE = "Directions for historical linguistics",
    EDITOR = "W. P. Lehmann and Yakov Malkiel",
    TITLE = "Empirical foundations for a theory of language change",
    YEAR = "1968",
    BOOKSUBTITLE = "A symposium",
    LOCATION = "Austin, TX",
    PAGES = "95--195",
    PUBLISHER = "University of Texas Press"}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names in question are printed by the bibmacro `bybookauthor` that needs to be redefined analogous to `byauthor`

```
\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {}
    {\printnames[bybookauthor]{bookauthor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{bookauthor}{author}}}
```

By default `bybookauthor` is called before the `boobktitle` is printed. If we want to print the names after the title, we need to change the position of the macro in the driver. This can be done with `xpatch`'s `\xpatchbibdriver`

```
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock}
  {}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style = authoryear-comp,
    language = nynorsk,
    sortlocale = nn_NO]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}
  {\printtext[parens]}
  {\setunit*{\addperiod\space}\printtext}
  {}{}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{nynorsk}{
    bibliography = {Tilvisingar},
    editor = {styr\adddot},
    editors = {styr\adddot},
    founder = {grunnar},
    founders = {grunnarar},
    references = {Tilvisingar},
    byauthor = {skreiv},
    byeditor = {styrde},
    byfounder = {grunnade},
    volume = {band},
    volumes = {band},
}

\renewbibmacro*{bybookauthor}{%
  \ifnamesequal{author}{bookauthor}
    {}
    {\printnames[bybookauthor]{bookauthor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{bookauthor}{author}}}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock}
  {}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{byauthor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    or
    test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {}
    {\printnames[byauthor]{author}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{author}{author}}}

\newbibmacro*{byeditorx:i}[1]{%
  \ifnameundef{#1}
    {}
    {\printnames[by#1]{#1}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{#1}{editor}%
     \newunit}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editor}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditorx}{%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editora}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editorb}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx:i}{editorc}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \bibstring{bytranslator}}}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{translator}
    {}
    {\printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{withothers}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{flo1906,
    AUTHOR = "R. Flo",
    TITLE = "Midlandsmaal",
    YEAR = "1906",
    EDITOR = "Arne Garborg",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PUBLISHER = "Olaf Norlis forlag",
    SUBTITLE = "Etter framlegge fraa rettskrivingsnemndi i 1899"}
@BOOK{ordbogoverdetdanskesprog,
    TITLE = "Ordbog over det danske sprog",
    YEAR = "1919--56",
    EDITOR = "H. Juul-Jensen",
    EDITORA = "Verner Dahlerup",
    EDITORATYPE = "founder",
    LOCATION = "K{\o}benhavn",
    NOTE = "Udgivet af det danske sprog- og litteraturselskab",
    PUBLISHER = "Gyldendalske boghandel. Nordisk forlag",
    VOLUMES = "28"}
@INBOOK{torp1909,
    AUTHOR = "Alf Torp",
    BOOKTITLE = "Gamalnorsk ordbok",
    TITLE = "Gamalnorsk ordavleiding",
    YEAR = "1909",
    BOOKAUTHOR = "Marius H{\ae}gstad and Alf Torp",
    BOOKSUBTITLE = "Med nynorsk tyding",
    LOCATION = "Kristiania",
    PAGES = "xxviii--lxxi",
    PUBLISHER = "Det norske samlaget (Landsmaals-laget)"}
@INCOLLECTION{weinreich1968,
    AUTHOR = "Uriel Weinreich and William Labov and Marvin I. Herzog",
    BOOKTITLE = "Directions for historical linguistics",
    EDITOR = "W. P. Lehmann and Yakov Malkiel",
    TITLE = "Empirical foundations for a theory of language change",
    YEAR = "1968",
    BOOKSUBTITLE = "A symposium",
    LOCATION = "Austin, TX",
    PAGES = "95--195",
    PUBLISHER = "University of Texas Press"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Torp, Alf. 1909. Gamalnorsk ordavleiding. Gamalnorsk ordbok. Med nynorsk tyding. Marius Hægstad og Alf Torp skreiv. Kristiania: Det norske samlaget (Landsmaals-laget), s. xxviii–lxxi.]